# ORA-24816: Expanded non LONG bind data supplied after actual LONG or LOB column

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, oracle11g

I'm getting following exception, while updating table in Hibernate

ORA-24816: Expanded non LONG bind data supplied after actual LONG or LOB column

I have extracted sql query as well, it looks like

```
Update table_name set columnName (LOB)=value, colmun2 (String with 4000)=value where id=?;
```

Entity class

```
class Test{

    @Lob
    private String errorText;

    @Column(length = 4000)
    private String text;
}
```

Please help me, what is wrong in this

Thanks
Ravi Kumar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found issue.
1. When hibernate updating data in DB and entity has 4000 chars column and lob type column  then hibernate throwing this exception

I have solved this issue by writing two update queires
1. First i have saved entity by using Update()
2. Written another update query for lob column update

Thanks
ravi

Comment: Another alternative approach until hibernate 3 is, you can rename entity fields by adding prefix as "z_" this way hibernate will put all fields in at end of statement.

Answer (score 8):

Running `oerr ora 24816` to get the details on the error yields:

```
$ oerr ora 24816
24816, ... "Expanded non LONG bind data supplied after actual LONG or LOB column"
// *Cause:  A Bind value of length potentially > 4000 bytes follows binding for
//          LOB or LONG.
// *Action: Re-order the binds so that the LONG bind or LOB binds are all
//          at the end of the bind list.
```

So another solution that uses only 1 query would be to move your LOB/LONG binds after all your non-LOB/LONG binds.  This may or may not be possible with Hibernate.  Perhaps something more like:

```
update T set column2 (String with 4000)=:1, columnName (LOB)=:3 where id=:2;
```

This DML limitation appears to have been around since at least Oracle 8i.

*References:*

- http://openacs.org/forums/message-view?message_id=595742
- https://community.oracle.com/thread/417560

Answer (score 4):

I do realise that this thread is quite old, but I thought I'd share my own experience with the same error message here for future reference.

I have had the exact same symptoms (i.e. ORA-24816) for a couple of days. I was a bit side-tracked by various threads I came across suggesting that this was related to order of parameter binding. In my case this was not a problem. Also, I struggled to reproduce this error, it only occurred after deploying to an application server, I could not reproduce this through integration tests.

However, I took a look at the code where I was binding the parameter and found:

```
preparedStatement.setString(index, someStringValue);
```

I replaced this with:

```
preparedStatement.setClob(index, new StringReader(someStringValue));
```

This did the trick for me.

[This thread from back in 2009](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1324028?start=0&tstart=0) was quite useful.

Answer (score 3):

I have also encountered same error in oracle db and foudn that [Hibernate Guys fixed here](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-4635?focusedCommentId=47068&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-47068)

In my case we were already using hiberante 4.3.7 but didnt mention that field is Lob in Entity

**Reproducing Steps**

1. Have fields with varchar2 datatype and clob data type.Make sure your column name are in this alphabetic order clob_field,varchar_two_field1,varchar_two_field2.
2. Now update clob_field with < 2000 bytes and varchar_two_field1 with 4000 bytes size.
3. This should end up with error **ORA-24816: Expanded non LONG bind data supplied after actual LONG or LOB column**

**Solution**

1. Make sure you have hiberante 4.1.8, < 4.3.0.Beta1
2. Annotate your clob/blob field in respective Entity as

   ```
   import javax.persistence.Lob;  
   ...
       @Lob
       @Column(name = "description")
       private String description;  
   ....
   ```

If you want to see the difference , by after making above changes enable debug for sql statements by setting `"true"` for `"hibernate.show_sql"` in persistence.xml.

Answer (score 2):

I came across this issue today while trying to Insert the data into a table. To avoid this error, Just keep all the fields having **"LOB"** data type at the end of the insert statement.

**For Example**

> Table1 has 8 Fields (Field1,Field2,.... Field8 etc..),

of which

> Field1 and Field2 are of CLOB data types
>
> and the rest are Varchar2 Data types

. Then while inserting the data make sure you keep **Field1 and Field2** values at the end like below.

```
 INSERT INTO TABLE1 ( Field3,Field4,Field5,Field6,Field7,Field8,Field1,Field2)  
    Values ('a','b','c','d','e','f','htgybyvvbshbhabjh','cbsdbvsb')
```

Answer (score 2):

Place your LOB binding at the last. See if that solves the issue..